# Calabash-android: getting different position results in the queries

Tags: android, ruby, offset, calabash

I'm looking for exact position of the 'messages button'

Running the query below:

`irb(main):032:0> query("* id:'messagesButtonImage'")`

And get the result:

```
[
    [0] {
                        "id" => "messagesButtonImage",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                   "visible" => true,
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.widget.ImageView{52d88ec8 V.ED.... ..S..... 136,12-238,84 #7f0d00b6 app:id/messagesButtonImage}",
                     "class" => "android.widget.ImageView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 1677,
            "center_x" => 187,
              "height" => 72,
                   "y" => 1641,
               "width" => 102,
                   "x" => 136
        }
    }
]
```

The 'y' is 1641.

Now - running the next query:

`query("* id:'messagesButtonImage'", :y)`

But getting:

```
[
    [0] 12.0
]
```

The keyboard is hidden in both queries.

The queries for the x, height or width works fine.

What is the query syntax to get the exact results?

Answer (score 1):

I found a query that works:

`query("* id:'messagesButtonImage'")[0]['rect']['y']`

Hope it is helping,